# JSTL dropdown is empty in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm trying to populate my jsp's dropdown using jstl. My jsp is mapped like this.

```
 <servlet>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/views/dilini/newjsp.jsp</jsp-file>
    <servlet-name>newjsp</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>newjsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/newjsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also this is my jstl loaded dropdown.

```
     <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn2 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu2" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
               <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
                <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute="${person.getId()}" class="list2" href="#">${person.getName()}</a></li>
                </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is my controller servlet.

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        CasualLeaveService service1 = new CasualLeaveServiceImpl();
        List<Person> personList = service1.searchName();
        if (personList.isEmpty()) {
            response.getWriter().write("EMPTY ");
        } else {
            response.getWriter().write("NOT EMPTY ");
            request.setAttribute("personList", personList);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/newjsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run my controller by own it shows something like this. 

[image]

I really don't understand why dropdown is not visible the servlet. Please help me. Thank you.

***Added more to answer. Hope this will help some one.*** 

**Also I should add another one when jsp is calling "by clicking button or clicking link" you should first got to    controller and then controller will redirect the jsp. This was the missing part.**

Once again thank you all for your support.

Comment: Ehm, what's your problem? Everything looks good to me.

Comment: Problem is when I load the jsp list is empty. The image is when I'm running the servlet.

Comment: Of course it is empty! The servlet generates the `personList`, without the servlet there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek can you please tell me how to populate this list?

Comment: Well, you can copy the relevant code from the servlet into your JSP (as a scriptlet), but I would **not** recommend that. You are doing it right (except you shouldn't use `response.getWriter().write(...);` in the servlet), the servlet should play the controller part, the JSP should be only the view. See e.g. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/ for more details on MVC architecture.

Comment: I'm also agree with you about scriptlet. Thats why I need a real answer.

Comment: Well, the real answer is: continue using the servlet to load data, and JSP just to display them. Avoid referencing the JSP pages directly in URL, your links (form actions) should always lead to a servlet, and servled decides (according to the loaded data, or an error), which JSP should be used to display the data/error message.

Comment: Well what is ur anser on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer:

Your current approach is good, continue using the servlet for loading the data, and JSP only to display them (or an error message). I.e. avoid using JSP URLs in your links/form actions, use always an URL of a servlet, the servlet should load the data and then **forward** the request to an appropriate JSP. It is exactly the [Model/View/Controller](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) pattern/architecture.

Just few suggested changes to your code:

- Remove the newjsp mapping from your web.xml, the JSP pages shouldn't be available directly, only via servlet.

JSP: handle the case of empty list

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn2 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu2" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
        <c:if test="${empty personList}">
            <li>No person available</li>
        </c:if>
        <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute="${person.getId()}" class="list2" href="#">${person.getName()}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Servlet: do not tackle with the response, that's the task of a view; just load data and forward to the view (JSP)

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        CasualLeaveService service1 = new CasualLeaveServiceImpl();
        List<Person> personList = service1.searchName();
        request.setAttribute("personList", personList);
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/dilini/newjsp.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // bad practice, use some logger
        request.setAttribute("error", "Error loading person list: " + e.getMessage());
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/dilini/error.jsp"); // you have to create one
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a perfect answer. Thank you. :) Also I should add another one when jsp is calling "by clicking button or clicking link" you should first got to    controller and then controller will redirect the jsp. This was the missing part. Still your answer is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be accessing the properties using the property name rather than the getXXX() way you are doing it now.

```
<li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute="${person.id}" class="list2" href="#">${person.name}</a></li>
```

Comment: :( still no output. I think list can't see the controller.